# How do I read an input file in ruby using < in command line?

Tags: ruby, input, terminal, command, output

I want this to work:

```
./search.sh < inputFile.json
```

and

```
./search.sh < inputFile2.json
```

That will output something different depending on the file. I would then like to do this:

```
(./search.sh < inputFile.json) > results.json
```

I'm sure that syntax is wrong. Is anyone able to put me in the right direction? I can't find how to do this in my ruby script (I'm using .sh but it's ruby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the content of the input files will be different and you will have some logic to determine that. You can actually just read that file input as if it was entered as text by the user and do whatever you need to do with it.

Example:

**test.rb**

```
puts gets.chomp
```

**testfile**

```
test
```

**Terminal**

```
$ ruby test.rb < testfile
$ test
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. I was using gets.chomp but didn't realize if you feed it a file, it will complete the gets.chomp immediately. (Usually I use gets.chomp when prompting users for input. 
Thanks so much this helped a ton!

Comment: @p11y The chomp is not necessary and is dependant on what you want to do with the input, I was just trying to show that it can be used as text normally entered into a program.

Answer (score 5):

You have multiple options.

## Read from stdin

One option is to read from stdin. You can for example do in `search.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

input = $stdin.read

puts "here's the input i got:"
puts input
```

Suppose we have a file `foo.txt` which looks like this

```
foo
bar
baz
```

then you can use it with a unix pipe

```
~$ ./search.sh < foo.txt
here's the input i got:
foo
bar
baz
```

which is equivalent to

```
~$ cat foo.txt | ./search.sh
here's the input i got:
foo
bar
baz
```

although this is useless use of cat and just meant to serve demonstration purposes. You can not only pipe files but also output from other commands

```
~$ echo "hello, world!" | ./search.sh
here's the input i got:
hello, world!
```

if you want to redirect the output to another file, do

```
~$ ./search.sh < foo.txt > bar.txt
~$ cat bar.txt
here's the input i got:
foo
bar
baz
```

## Read file from Ruby

Another way is to just pass the file name as argument and read the file directly from Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

file = ARGV.first
input = File.read(file)

puts "here's the input i got:"
puts input
```

Usage:

```
~$ ./search.sh foo.txt
here's the input i got:
asfdg
sdf
sda
f
sdfg
fsd
```

and again to redirect the output use `>`

```
~$ ./search.sh foo.txt > bar.txt
```